# The unit for blood cell number is different in labevent. How could I unify them?

Tags: mimic-iii

I just want to unify the unit for lab measurement data in labevent table for mimiciii. But I found there are two types of units for counting numbers of blood cell: #/uL and %. I could not find the source of this unit "%".

I guess the unit is different according to different types of blood cell. How should i unify them? The table below shows the question. The first column is loinc_code. The third column is value. The last column is unit for this value

[image: labevent table]

Thanks for answering!

Comment: This was a bug but has been fixed now in MIMIC-III v1.4 - I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You've actually found a bug in MIMIC-III v1.3. Some of the CD counts were muddled - actual counts (#/uL) were merged with percentages, and vice versa.

If you look at the LOINC code for percent CD8 (8137-2), you can see the same issue:

```
 loinc | valueuom | count
------ | -------- | ------
8137-2 | #/uL     |  1580
8137-2 | %        |   566
```

edit: This has been fixed in v1.4. The same LOINC code now provides the same data:

`select loinc_code, valueuom, count(*) as numobs
from d_labitems dl
inner join labevents le
on dl.itemid = le.itemid
where loinc_code = '8137-2'
group by loinc_code, valueuom order by numobs;`

.. gives

```
loinc_code | valueuom | numobs 
-----------+----------+--------
8137-2     | %        |   2188
```